# Is there a norm on the space of bounded functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous at the origin?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

For the space of continuous and bounded functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we can always define the supremum norm without any problems.

I say that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is *bounded* if the function $|f|: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded in the standard sense. (I don't know if this is standard terminology. Also note that $| \cdot|$ denotes the modulus.)

**Questions:**

**1.** Can we use the supremum norm on bounded continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to define a norm on the space of bounded continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$?

**2.** If so, can we take this even further and find a norm on the space of bounded functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous at the origin (but not necessarily anywhere else)?

**Motivation:** By [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions), the characteristic function $f$ of any finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra inherited from the Euclidean topology is continuous at the origin and [bounded by $f(0)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#Most_common_usage). So if such a norm as asked for in **2.** exists, it would provide [another way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) to define a topology on the space of such finite measures, due to the one to one correspondence between finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and their characteristic functions. [(See also)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302451/are-continuous-distributions-satisfying-the-hypothesis-of-the-clt-generic)

Comment: It seems to me that this should be easy. The space $\mathcal B$ of bounded functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ is Banach with the sup norm. Functions which are continuous at the origin are a closed vector subspace of $\mathcal B$, and so they too form a Banach space.

Comment: all norms are continuous because they are Lipschitz.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So we don't need to assume (uniform) continuity everywhere for that to work? Or am I confusing supremum with maximum (attained supremum)? I thought we might have needed uniform continuity because $\mathbb{R}$ isn't compact so we can't use Heine-Cantor. EDIT: never mind it seems https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282121/is-the-space-of-bounded-functions-with-the-maximums-norm-a-banach-space-and-even  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282609/is-the-space-of-bounded-functions-with-the-supremum-norm-a-banach-algebra  should I delete this question? It seems dumb(er) now.

Comment: I don't think you should erase the question. The answer might be easy, but not "dumb". Moreover, the remarks at the end are interesting, and indeed, I think that something like that is done somewhere in probability.